# How can I stop Microsoft Word from changing my APA citations?

Tags: microsoft-word, citations, bibliography

I am currently writing a report and I am using the APA Style Guide for my citations. So far when I added a new citation it would look something like this:

> some text about citation (Author, Year)

For some reason, Microsoft Word decided to change it so all my citations look like this:

> some text about citation (Author, Name of Publication, Year)

This change only applies to the new citations that I add and does not change any of the previous ones. If I try and add some of my old citations they still look like the first example.

I don't understand what is happening and I haven't been able to revert it. Every new citation that I add stays like in the second example. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @tchrist I'll migrate this question to Super User. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Obrigado: I’ll migrate it for you.